# SQL Обновление зависимых друг от друга полей в записи

Tags: sql, update, порядок

Есть таблица Price, в которой имеются следующие поля

Mass ! PriceKg !  TotalPrice !

Допустим, мне нужно сделать update этой записи, изменить поля mass и PriceKg, чтобы TotalPrice обновился согласно новым значениям.
Я бы это сделал так:

UPDATE Table SET Mass=2, PriceKg=3, TotalPrice=Mass*PriceKg;

Но не уверен, что UPDATE выполняется в том порядке, что я указал в команде - с лева на право. Не может ли так случиться, что сначала пересчитается TotalPrice, а только потом Mass и PriceKg. В гугле при беглом поиске о порядке полей UPDATE ничего не нашел. Гарантирует ли SQL такое поведение, или порядок может зависить от реализации ПО на сервере?

Comment: Зависит от реализации SQL-сервера.

Comment: А я бы сделал так: `UPDATE Table SET Mass=2, PriceKg=3, TotalPrice=2*3;` и не ломал голову. *Гарантирует ли SQL такое поведение* Стандарт SQL вообще не описывает порядок вычисления выражений. Да и мануалы конкретных серверов не грешат подобной слабостью (исключение, пожалуй MS ACCESS, где цепные вычисления со ссылкой на предыдущее поле - документированы). Если доступен исходный код, можно посмотреть там.

Comment: PS. Но вообще хранение данных, которые однозначно вычисляются из других данных, называется "переопределённые данные", и является потенциальной точкой нарушения непротиворечивости данных.

Comment: Как правильно выполнять такую операцию? В два прохода? Сначала Uodate для аргументов, на втором - вычисление?

Comment: UPDATE Table SET Mass=2, PriceKg=3, TotalPrice=2*3

Такой UPDATE не пойдет, так как пример упрощенный. Сам PriceKg зависит от других полей записи, умноженных на коэффициенты, передаваемые в хранимую процедуру.
Может вы и правы про переопределение, но есть один нюанс. Пересчет цен делается условно раз в месяц, а поиск по базе - тысячи раз в час. С точки зрения распределения машинных мощностей лучше хранить избыток данных чем постоянно пересчитывать.